# sql server 2012 : how to optimize this like % query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

This query takes too much time, so I try to optimize it. Do you have any idea or suggestion ?

I tried with fulltext on a procedure and a while loop ... it gets worst ( dbo.url has more than 100 000 lines ; dbo.url where status = 'tocheck' only 1000)

```
select tocheck.*
from dbo.url tocheck inner join dbo.url done 
on tocheck.id != done.id 
and tocheck.url like done.url+'%' 
and done.status in ('tocheck','todo','done') 
where tocheck.status = 'tocheck'
```

Edit :

I call a webservice multiple times with different urls : 
urls look like http://ws.com/query?p1=a&p2=b (url1).

If I already called url http://ws.com/query?p1=a (url2), i don't want to call url1 cause :

```
url1 like url2+'%'
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit2 :

I add a column suburl that contains 'query?p1=a' for each url and modify the query :

```
select tocheck.*
from dbo.url tocheck inner join dbo.url done 
on tocheck.id != done.id 
and tocheck.suburl = done.suburl --NEW
and tocheck.url like done.url+'%' 
and done.status in ('tocheck','todo','done') 
where tocheck.status = 'tocheck'
```

More than 10 times shorter ... Phew !!

Comment: It would be great if you show us some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Why can't you compare tocheck.url like done.url+'%' ? This should be possible by using an index. Check query plan.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to Achieve by this kind of join?

Comment: @user2672165 : i made this modification but doesn't seem to improve that much ... thanks anyway

Comment: @user2762275: But do you have index on url columns and are they used?

Answer (score 1):

I think because of joining the table to itself through ids not equal there is much overhead as this is a cartesian product only excluding self joins for same id.

I suggest trying with a subquery. Then the outer query returns only 1000 (as you mentioned) tochecks whereas the subquery additionally excludes urls starting with the same characters:

```
select
   tocheck.*
from
   dbo.url tocheck
where
   tocheck.status = 'tocheck'
and
    tocheck.id not in (
        select
            done.id
        from
            dbo.url done
        where
            tocheck.url like done.url+'%'
        and
            done.status in ('tocheck','todo','done')
    )
```

Comment: The subquery didn't work ( for optimization ). but your idea of working with urls that start with the same characters help me a lot ! ( I add a column that contains 'query?p1=a' to minimize the jointure   and therefore to maximize the performance).